# JS React short circuit for onpress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I want to disable "onPress" if a parameter isEnabled === false,

works like:

```
const RightTitle = ({children, onPress, isEnabled}) => (
  <Right
    onPress={isEnabled === true ? onPress : console.log("chuchas")}
    isEnabled={isEnabled}>
    <CTALight>{children}</CTALight>
  </Right>
)
```

But if I do a "short circuit" to avoid the ternary I get an error

> onPress is not a function

```
const RightTitle = ({children, onPress, isEnabled}) => (
  <Right
    onPress={isEnabled && {onPress}  }
    isEnabled={isEnabled}>
    <CTALight>{children}</CTALight>
  </Right>
)
```

edit: the same problem if no brackets for "onPress"

```
onPress={isEnabled && onPress  }
```

How to evaluate my "isEnabled" to allow the button onPress?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just omit the `{ }` around `onPress`: `onPress={isEnabled && onPress}`

Comment: thanks @Samathingamajig same problem with out the brackets

Comment: `onPress={isEnabled ? onPress : undefined}`

Comment: If it's giving you issues after that, the issue lies in your component `Right` not actually having logic to deal with when onPress is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onPress` should take a function which can be invoked. In the case that `isEnabled` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), you're going to get that falsy value in return (eg: if it is `false` you will get *false* back, which is not a function). You can wrap your call in your own function, which will either return the `isEnabled` if it is falsy, or invoke your onPress handler:

```
onPress={() => isEnabled && onPress()}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the logical AND (`&&`) then you would need to check in the child that the `onPress` callback is valid. `false` and `undefined` are not functions and can't be invoked as one.

```
onPress={isEnabled && onPress}
```

Right child component

```
onPress && onPress()
```

or

```
onPress?.()
```

Alternatively you would need to just provide a NOOP function the `Right` component could call without needing to check first.

```
onPress={isEnabled ? onPress : () => {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `isEnabled` is false, then onPress === `false`, which isn't a function. You'd need to append an empty function to the end to make this work.

`onPress={isEnabled && onPress || (() => {})}`

```js
isEnabled = true;
onPress = () => console.log("press");

console.log(typeof (isEnabled && onPress));
console.log(typeof (isEnabled && onPress || (()=>{})));

isEnabled = false;

console.log(typeof (isEnabled && onPress));
console.log(typeof (isEnabled && onPress || (()=>{})));
```